# No route matches [PATCH] "/order.2"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Have tried using similar questions on SO to fit to my specific case for the past hour or two but it hasn't been working.

I am getting the following error when trying to edit and `order` but not when I am creating an `order` which is why I am confused because I use the same form partial for it which starts with `<%=form_for(@order, :html => {class: "form-horizontal", role: "form"})do |f|%>`

My `routes.rb` are:

```
get 'dashboard', to: 'order#index'
get 'order', to: 'order#new'
post 'order', to: 'order#create'
get 'edit/:id', to: 'order#edit', as:'edit'
post 'edit/:id', to: 'order#update'

get 'accept/:id', to: 'order#accept', as: 'accept'
get 'submit/:id', to: 'order#submit', as: 'submit'
```

I have no clue what's going on because I am used to `POST` and `GET` but not `PATCH` and i've tried researching my issue on my own but I cannot find any solutions.

**ANSWER IS IN CHAT IN COMMENTS**

Comment: make this `patch 'edit/:id', to: 'order#update'`  for update your form need patch method instead of post

Comment: doesn't fix it for some reason

Comment: make order as resources

Comment: can you show me `link_to` for edit action

Comment: `<button class="btn btn-error"><%= link_to "Edit Order", edit_path(id: o.id)%></button>`

Comment: dont need to pass value in hash format

Comment: just pass with this way `edit_path(o.id)`

Comment: this solution throws the error `No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"order"} missing required keys: [:id]` on the line `<%=form_for(@order, :html => {class: "form-horizontal", role: "form"})do |f|%>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148112/discussion-between-uzaif-and-jack).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this problem you have to first update your routes as below code

#### routes.rb

```
  resources :order, except: [:show, :destroy]
```

create one helper function for add create time and update time link

```
def order_form_path(object)
    object.new_record? ? "/order" : order_path
end
```

now use above helper function in your `form_for` partial

```
 <%=form_for(@order,url:order_form_path(@order)%>
```

hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

your route order.2 means you are doing something like order_path(@someid) in your view but no route is defined for order that require an id...if you need to route specific id do something like this

`get 'order/:id' , to: 'controller#action' , as: :order`

and then in your views

`order_path(@someid)`

Patch and put are use to update data not create..